# Jafafx listview set background color

Tags: listview, javafx

How can one change background color of the listview? 
I've set cell color to transparent through css, but i didn't manage to change the color of the listivew.

here is my css

```
.messages-listview {
// -fx-background-image: url("/images/9.jpg"); this works

-fx-background-color: black; /* this doesnt*/
}

.messages-listview .list-cell {
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

I can set any image as the background but unfrotunately i can not set custom color. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: "-fx-background-color: black;" is working for me.

Comment: @UlukBiy i found out what was the problem, i accidentally changed default list-view in my css, so everything works fine, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Background of listView like following,

```
.list-view {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3c3c;
}
```